# Editing emacs init.el does not take effect

Tags: debian, emacs

I want emacs to store all my backup files in the directory `~/.save`.

I put the following code into my `init.el` file:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist `(("." . "~/.saves")))
```

However, this change does not take effect. The backup files are still generated in the directory where the original edited files are stored.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The doc says that the directory name can be absolute or relative. But it doesn't say it can make use of `~`. You might try this: \`(("." . ,(expand-file-name "~/.saves"))), to expand it to an absolute file name (or just use the absolute file name directly).

Comment: @Drew Unfortunately both didn't work.

Comment: Perhaps it depends on when you set the variable in your init file. Have you checked, using `C-h v`, that after Emacs startup and initialization the variable has the value you think you set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quote is not the good one or/and you need to add a slash at end:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.saves/")))
```